# Elixir Dynamo start multiple apps

Tags: elixir

What is the best way to start multiple apps using Dynamo. When we create the project dynamo generates a default app. I would like to add one more app in lib and start it as soon as i start the server.

However, i tried putting it in lib folder, apps folder also modified mix.exs but mix compile is not generating the app file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it !!!

To work with multiple apps in same project create umbrella projects and inside the apps you can create one dynamo application and one normal application and inside dynamo you can add other application as a dependency in mix.exs